# Runnig tests on docker from PhpStorm does not start apache2

Tags: php, docker, testing, docker-compose, phpstorm

I managed to configure PhpStrom with docker based on `php7.1-apache` image. `docker-compose.yml` is below:

```
version: '3'

services:

  www:
    image: php:7.1-apache
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

And in my app I have unit tests and api tests. There is no problem with running unit tests from phpstorm. Remote interpreter is being used correctly.

**The problem is with api tests that make http requests to web-server.** I figured out that apache2 daemon is not started at all.

`docker ps --no-trunc` shows:

```
php /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --no-configuration --filter '/(::should_do_something)( .*)?$/' ExampleTest /var/www/html/tests/ExampleTest.php --teamcity
```

And in container I can see:

```
$:~/workspace/phpstorm-docker$ docker-compose exec www bash
root@aa13971914b2:/var/www/html/tests# service apache2 status
[FAIL] apache2 is not running ... failed!
```

**That's because PhpStrom does not start `apache2-foreground` process.**

If I put `sleep(15)` before api test execution and inside container run:

```
service apache2 start
```

Test is passing.

Do you know how to make PhpStorm to start also apache2 web server to have complete container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm ignores the entrypoint when it starts containers via Docker Compose: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-42228

Probably adding `command: service apache2 start` to your `docker-compose.yml` would do the trick here.